# On a linear regression model, If Price went up over time, would a positive or negative residual be preferable in order to get the best price?

Tags: regression, residuals

From my understanding, a negative residual would be preferable because the price point would be lower than the others at the same point in time. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

A residual is Actual - Predicted.  So a negative residual means that the Predicted is larger than the actual or for your case: you got a good deal.

This is all assuming you have a good relevant model and all that.  From what I gather it is just price as a function of time so a simple trend line and we want a lower price.  For this simple example you want the negative residual more-so than the positive assuming you want to buy low and 'preferable' doesn't mean something else.